# JQuery Mobile - Optimizing Layout of Radio Button Groups - Different Size Devices

Tags: layout, jquery-mobile, formatting

We are testing jquery mobile for an application targeting both phone size devices and tablets.  In one part of the application questions are asked followed by one or more groups of possible answers (each group can have 1 radio button as the answer).

On a small device (phone)  answer groups can be done vertically with multiple radio buttons per group) and the UI is fine albeit requires scrolling.

However on a tablet where there is significantly more real estate, we want to have a group with 2 or more columns of radio buttons and to place them horizontally with overflow to a new "row" depending on available realestate to optimize available realestate and minimize or preferably eliminate scrolling and of course not having radio buttons stretching crazily accross a much wider area as jquery mobile seems to do.

Help Please...

Answer (score 0):

I was reading about the same issue yesterday. You have to use **`media`** queries to make **Responsive CSS**.

Here is great guide from [**IBM**](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/mo-jquery-responsive-design/index.html)

Hope it helps! (also rate me if its good :))